# What is the best way for me to Save & Load gamestate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I was just wondering, is it hard to save / load gamestate?

I'm creating a game and I want to be able to save the gamestate in case there's a call or the player ends the game to continue to play another time or the game crashes, then give the choice to start a new game or continue where he/she left off.

The gamestate contains SFX, background music (the background music should continue where it ended). (buttons to both), a grid full of uiimages (the images should reappear at the same spot they where before the game ended), score (both highscore and playerscore), level and 3 more uiimages outside the grid.

What do you recommend?

Are there any good tutorials out there? I've checked but I only seem to find for cocos2d and I'm not using cocos2d at the moment.

```
//Load the saved gamestate
- (void)loadGameState {
    // Set up the file manager and documents path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSMutableData *gameData;
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder;
    NSString *documentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameState.dat"];
    gameData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentPath]; 
    decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:gameData];

    NSLog(@"INFO - GameScene: Loading saved game duration."); 
    //timeSinceGameStarted = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"timeSinceGameStarted"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved game score."); 
    playerscore = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"playerscore"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved high score."); 
    highscore = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"highscore"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved level."); 
    level = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Level"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INFO - GameScene: Loading game time data."); 

    [decoder release];
}

//Saving the current gamestate
-(void)saveGameState {
    NSLog(@"Saving game state");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *gameStatePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameState.dat"];

    NSMutableData *gameData; 
    NSKeyedArchiver *encoder; 
    gameData = [NSMutableData data]; 
    encoder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:gameData];

    // Archive the games timer settings
    NSNumber *savedGameStartTime = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds]; 
    //NSNumber *savedTimeSinceGameStarted = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:timeSinceGameStarted]; 
    NSNumber *savedPlayerScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:playerscore];
    NSNumber *savedHighScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:highscore];
    NSNumber *savedcurrentlevel = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:level];

    [encoder encodeObject:savedGameStartTime forKey:@"gameStartTime"];
    //[encoder encodeObject:savedTimeSinceGameStarted forKey:@"timeSinceGameStarted"];

    [encoder encodeObject:savedPlayerScore forKey:@"playerscore"]; 
    [encoder encodeObject:savedHighScore forKey:@"highscore"]; 

    [encoder encodeObject:savedcurrentlevel forKey:@"Level"]; 

    // Finish encoding and write the contents of gameData to file
    [encoder finishEncoding]; 
    [gameData writeToFile:gameStatePath atomically:YES]; 
    [encoder release];

    // Tell the game controller that a resumed game is available
    //sharedGameController.resumedGameAvailable = YES;
}
```

Comment: You can save gamestate in Sqlite database

Comment: ok ? and how do I do that? this if my first game so I'm still quite new to this stuff

Answer (score 1):

The one method that comes to my mind would be to store all of this information in a plist or similar; the coordinates and positions of things, the time of the music track etc, and then when the user is presented with the option to resume their last session, you can just read the contents of said plist and put everything back where it was.

I understand this is a particularly crude answer, but this methodology has worked in the 2 & 3D apps I have worked on in the past - admittedly we were only tracking a few dozen items - I am sure your game is likely to be much larger.

In response to your comment:

To accomplish this, I used NSUserDefaults - so you will find some good information by looking at the class reference on the Apple site. Create a NSUserDefaults member in a relevant place which can then poll your graphics' instances and music classes etc for how far along they are - so you'll need to write a method that returns this information for each class that you want to save - or: for each frame, get the respective classes to automatically write their latest positions etc to your defaults file. To setup the defaults file...

```
yourNSUserDefaultsMember = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource: @"Defaults" ofType: @"plist"]]];
```

In order for this to work, you need to create a plist file called Defaults or whatever you like. Then using the method calls located in the class reference, you can easily write strings and ints etc to it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. do you have any good examples, URL links or stuff like that that I can take a look at? 

I think my game is actually smaller. it's just a puzzle game :)

Comment: I'll take a look at it. thanks! is there a way to reach you if I get stuck or if I have any questions? I'm guessing that you like most of us don't spend 24-7 in here ;)

Comment: Just throw up another comment and I'll try my best to advise :) Good luck!

Comment: Hey!, I've updated the question with the save and load gamestate methods that I've written. I found a book called learning iOS game programming and there was the author talked about these two methods. I've so far tried to save/load the highscore and the player score as well as the current time on the countdown timer and the current level. I'm not sure if it works though cause I'm not sure how to make it interact with my main menu, where I have a continue and a new game button. the continue button shall be accessable when there is a saved gamestate

Comment: It all looks about right, the work you've now done. As soon as the player begins their first game and the timer hits 1 second or whatever, then the game has begun and you can set a BOOL to say that the main menu should now contain a "continue game" button. Upon clicking that, it will fire a method just like your loadGameState. It's all about putting things back where they were, like timers, scores and tiles... I'm afraid I don't know anything about your NSKeyedArchiver but you need to use that data to create the old game scene.

Comment: Ok... I think I understand. :) The 2 methods that you saw in the update part are the only once I put in my game.m file. Do I need anything else to get this work? create a new file maybe? you mentioned something about the NSKeyedArchiver.

Comment: I only mentionned the NSKeyedArchiver class as I see you're using it but I don't know anything about it, so it's harder for me to try to advise you. You just need to make sure that you use your encoder object and save your attributes at the right time - could be once per frame, could be when they change, or could be only when the game is about to be closed down. Reading the scores back in should be as easy as you have saved them, then you need to handle their values to load back in the game - giving the user the impression of resuming their session.

Comment: I don't so much about NSKeyedArchiver either... I just found that book I mentioned about and this way was how they solved the save and load thing :) I'm still trying to learn how this all works. Specially since I'm still not saving the current time status as well as the positions of the bricks in my game. I'm still not even sure if I am actually saving anything... noob alert or what hehe :)

Comment: Well your first job is to get the writing and reading to the encoder working... then worry about using that data later on. Once you have done this first step, start checking all the info inside it at app launch - if they're not == nil or your default values then you need to add the "resume game" option. Then get this firing a blank method with an NSLog and then finally commence work on reading back out the stored values and then using them :)

Comment: Thanks for the great advice... I'll let you know how it turns out. :)